# cassandra operations queue is full

Tags: cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'm running datastax enterprise 4.5.1, with opscenter 5.1.1. These were installed from the standalone linux installers on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
$ cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.8.39 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
```

In the datastax-agent log, I have been seeing tons of these WARN messages:

```
WARN [Thread-11] 2015-04-23 13:13:49,005 7647864 operations dropped so far.
WARN [Thread-11] 2015-04-23 13:13:49,005 Cassandra operation queue is full, discarding cassandra operation
```

similarly, these errors:

```
WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2015-04-30 16:20:40,432 Cassandra operation queue is full, discarding cassandra operation
WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2015-04-30 16:20:40,432 9 operations dropped so far.
```

Can someone give me an idea of what causes these? The node seems to be operating ok, no obvious errors in system.log to correlate. In datastax-agent-env.sh file, I've set `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xmx256M"` but that doesn't eliminate the problem.

Comment: may want to try restarting agent

Comment: I tried restarting but it's only a temporary fix. After a few hours or a day, the warnings begin again. I'd like to resolve them. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these changes in the config:

The following settings were changed in the agent address.yaml file. The agent process will need to be restarted for these settings to take effect.

thrift_max_conns: 10
async_pool_size: 10
async_queue_size: 20000

https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204225789-Ops-Center-is-not-showing-any-metrics-in-the-UI-dashboard

Comment: I made the changes. I'll let you know if the errors continue.

Comment: almost 24 hours and no WARNings in agent.log. Thanks for the suggestion!